# Extend a prototype method

Tags: javascript, prototype

Now I have a prototype like:

```
function A() {}

A.prototype.run =  function () {
    console.log('run 1');
};
```

Given that I cannot change anything where A is at (no control over the source). I would like to extend the method `run`. Not only log `run 1`, also log `run 2`. I tried several different approaches, it does not work.

```
A.prototype.run = function () {
    this.run.call(this);
    console.log('run 2');
}
```

Or

```
A.prototype.run = function () {
    arguments.callee.call(this);
    console.log('run 2');
}
```

Anyone having a solution for this? I would rather not to copy what's inside the method `run`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A.prototype._run = A.prototype.run;
A.prototype.run = function () {
    this._run.call(this);
    console.log('run 2');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `run` method, saving a reference to it as such;

```
(function (orig) {

    A.prototype.run = function () {
        orig.apply(this, arguments);

        console.log('run 2');
    }

}(A.prototype.run));
```

This is similar to your first attempt, but preserves the first value of `run`, so you can effectively do `this.run.call(this)` as you attempted.